# Fastest way to transfer a lot of small files on server (without git)

Tags: linux, ftp, sftp

There are a lot of instances where I need to deploy a large amount of files on a server which in themselves are not that large as storage space goes, but SFTP and FTP transfer makes the process really slow.

Is there a faster way (a faster protocol) to transfer thousands of small files (1-30K)?

I am currently using compress->transfer->uncompress, but that's an overhead I'd like to avoid.

I have shell access to the server with a limited instruction set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`rsync`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/rsync) is pretty efficient with lots of small files:

```
$ rsync -a path/to/local/files/ server:path/to/remote/files/
```

Answer (score -2):

`cd path/to/local/files/` - where you want to copy your files.

`sftp server:path/to remote/files/` - from where you want to copy your files.

then to copy files use `get -r file_name` , in case if gives get: `Invalid flag -r` error, then use R instead of r.

Comment: Welcome to Super User.  The question asks for the fastest way to transfer a lot of files.  Your solution uses file_name as a parameter, which implies executing this manually for each file, perhaps twice re: invalid flag error.  That doesn't seem like it could be the fastest solution.